# Different outputs for each condition.get together group by all values - single mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here how my tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT,project_id VARCHAR(6),order_id VARCHAR(6),user_id VARCHAR(6),owner_id VARCHAR(6));

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES
  (1, 211541,   8614,   1605,   0),
  (2, 211541,   8614,   16079,  1605),
  (3, 210446,   0,      12312,  0),
  (4, 208216,   0,      16467,  14499),
  (5, 208216,   0,      14499,  0),
  (6, 208216,   0,      14499,  0),
  (7, 208216,   0,      16467,  14499),
  (8, 209377,   0,      7556,   0),
  (9, 209324,   0,      7556,   0),
  (10,201038,   8602,   9390,   101);
```

I have to check split Multiple condtion: 
Query Execution this kind of way.

**order_id != 0** 
    Initially goes to project_id,
    (i.e) 
1.project_id - 211541 then first condition (owner_id = 0) , select user_id 
        note: 
            - if not get user_id(empty result) - goes to second condition.
            - if get user_id - do not go to second condtion. 
  
2.project_id - 211541 - second condtion (owner_id != 0), select owner_id. 
 i got 
    **my_user_id**  
         1605 
         101

**order_id = 0** 
    (i.e) 
1.project_id - 208216 then first condition (owner_id = 0) , select group by user_id
        note: 
            - if not get user_id(empty result) - goes to second condition.
            - if get user_id - do not go to second condtion.
  
2.project_id - 208216 - second condtion (owner_id != 0), select group by owner_id.
 i got 
    **my_user_id**  
         12312
14499
7556
7556

Finally, i need this answer - group by my_user_id 
 **my_user_id**  
         1605
101
12312
14499
7556

**Note:**

I need single query.

Comment: what you have tried so far? it seems like you are asking to do your assignment.

Comment: Why not just so a simple WHERE order_id != 0 AND my_user_id IN (X,Y)? Your question seems a bit vague. Do you need specific conditions or also different outputs per each condition?

Comment: @patel....not like that.i can't find out solution. give me some idea.

Comment: @tobe....i need different outputs for each condition.finally together all values...- single query.

Comment: your conditions don't really make sense... can you label each condition and clarify the steps more please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just use an IF?

```
SELECT 
    IF (order_id = 0, user_id, owner_id) AS new_val
FROM my_table
GROUP BY new_val
```

when looking at it more it seems like you need a few more ifs.. something like this?

```
SELECT 
    if(order_id <> 0,
        if(owner_id = 0, user_id, owner_id), 
        if(user_id = 0, owner_id, user_id)
    ) AS new_val
FROM my_table
group by new_val
```

**this is what i understand from your conditions**

ill number them and then put them with the if conditions i'll build in a second

```
if the order_id is not 0,  -- 1
check to see if the owner_id is 0,

if owner_id = 0 -- 2
then pull in user_id -- 3

else owner_id is not 0  
and you pull in owner_id -- 4
```

to write this more like code..

```
if(order_id <> 0, if(owner_id <> 0, owner_id, user_id), some condition for when order_id is 0)
```

other case

```
if the order_id is 0
pull in user_id (grouped) 

if user_id = 0 -- 5
then pull in owner_id -- 6

else user_id is not 0
and pull in user_id -- 7
```

to put this with the other part replace the some other condition for when its 0.

```
--      1              2              3          4           5             6         7

if(order_id <> 0, if(owner_id = 0, user_id, owner_id), if(user_id = 0, owner_id, user_id))
```

now to format it so its readable

```
if(order_id <> 0, -- if its not 0
    if(owner_id = 0, user_id, owner_id), -- true condition
    if(user_id = 0, owner_id, user_id) -- false condition
)
```

am I correct?

Comment: @kumaravelmathivanan thanks, I tried to explain it as I saw it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'if'.
Eg

```
@result=if(1!=2,'yes','no');
```

Which would give result a value of 'yes'.
These can be nested to create complex conditions:

```
SET @value_a='no';
set @value_b='';
set @value_c=’test’;
SET @value_d=’’;


set @result=
(
select if(@value_a!=’no’,(SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE id= @value_a),
            if(@value_b!='',@value_b,
                if(@value_c!='',(select column2 from table2 where id=@value_a),
                    if(@value_d!='',(select  column3 from table3 where id=@value_a),
                        ‘I am a default value’
                    )
                )
            )
        )
);
```

Giving whatever select column2 from table2 where id=@value_a gives.

Comment: ?? huh? this is not what the OP was asking for. he want's the data.. look at his expected outcomes...

Comment: To quote JR as above the OP was not particularly clear hence my advice was CLEARLY stated as an abstraction, and Bruno you should be stating where there are errors not simply making a claim its invalid without correction - but still a downvote without any constructive addition. Still if you are happy playing the points game play on - others come here to share knowledge and actually help the OP.

Comment: were not playing the points game. I guess Bruno hasn't used user-defined-variables before. however... the OP asked for help getting a particular outcome. your solution uses 3 tables... he has one... your's prints out strings when he wants the actual values inside of his one table. I am on here to share knowledge and help the OP hence my answer to this question. your answer does not help the OP out and doesn't even get close to solving the issue.. and you don't have an explanation on what its doing.. hence the downvote. please don't make accusations on intentions when you don't know them.

Comment: I'll be happy to remove the downvote if you make your answer more workable to the OP's request.. read my answer if you want to understand it better, as I think i got a decent grasp on what he was asking.

Comment: @TimHigham Sorry I wasn't clear, I didn't make any claim, didn't vote either way, I just asked.